# Putting a line in a Plot using Ticks

Tags: plotting, ticks

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 10},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}},
 Ticks -> {
   Automatic, {0, 2.5, {5, Style["0.5", Red, 12], 1.5, Directive[Red, Thick]}, 7.5, 10}}
 ]
```

I have the folliwing code, where I want to draw a horizontal line, however I want the line to start from x=0 and finish at the end of x=axis. I believe the number the number 2.5 in the plot is responsible for the length, but I couldn't get what I wanted using different values. What am I missing?

Comment: Looks at the documentation of [`Ticks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html#16923): The `1.5` in your code above is the length, and makes the tick centered on the axis. If you want a one-sided tick, use e.g. `{1,0}` instead of `1.5`.

Comment: Thank you it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this:

```
Plot[{5, x}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {0, 2.5, {5, Style["5", Red, 12]}, 7.5, 10}}]
```

[image]

??

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you want to use a long Tick instead of a GridLine for drawing this line? GridLines automatically extend across the plot.

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}},
    GridLines -> {None, {5}}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

[image]

Comment: There was no specific, apparently this is a solution as well. Thank you.